# Extract values from IEnumerable variable

Tags: asp.net, lambda, entity-framework-6

```
InfowareEntities Infoware = new InfowareEntities();   
IEnumerable admn = Infoware.Admissions.Where(x => x.AdmissionNo == 1520002);
```

In my admission database table I have columns- admissionNo, firstname, lastname...
now from above lambda expression I need to get firstname.
Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Try chaining a select like this

```
.Where(x => x.AdmissionNo == 15200).select (n => n.FirstName)
```

to get a list of names.

Comment: I know that chirs, my question is how can i extract values from IEnumerable variable..

Comment: Well the result of my select will be an IEnumerable <string> and you have extracted what you need. What type are you enumerating? I suspect an Admission dto of some sort.

Comment: Are you expecting a list back? If not , don't use IEnumerable.  Use First () or FirstOrDefault (). Into Admission then pull the FirstName.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need this,

```
InfowareEntities Infoware = new InfowareEntities();   
IEnumerable admn = Infoware.Admissions.Where(x => x.AdmissionNo == 1520002);
var arrayOfFirstNames = admn.select(n => n.FirstName).ToArray();
```

You can also use "ToList();" if you want list of first names..